# Is there a quick way of dropping a Service Broker queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

I have been running a load test that involves a Service Broker queue over night. Something went wrong and the queue ended up with 1.3 million messages in it. I just want to clear these out, no backup and no logging required. The trouble is that when I try to drop the queue it is taking half an hour and then the log file fills up and the whole thing rolls back. Is there a quick and dirty way of flushing everything out the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the TOP 1 clause in the RECEIVE statement then it will receive all messages that meet the criteria, or setting it to a high number will allow you to clear the backlog in managable chunks.

The trick will be to 'blackhole' the messages so the result set isn't returned to the client.

Comment: Though this is the best answer I have found, it still isn't as quick as I would like. The trouble is that the RECEIVE statment only gets one conversation at a time regardless of how big you make the TOP n clause.

Answer (score 7):

You can clear all conversations at once with the following statement:

```
declare @conversationHandle uniqueidentifier 
select top 1 @conversationHandle = conversation_handle from sys.conversation_endpoints    
while @@rowcount = 1

begin    
     end conversation @conversationHandle with cleanup    
     select top 1 @conversationHandle = conversation_handle from sys.conversation_endpoints    
end
```

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked for me +1. There is a gotcha though: the situation where you have all the messages in a single conversation. In that case it may still run out of log space before the single conversation is cleared.